# jquery .toggle() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to learn JavaScript and Jquery. I want to make a button that hide my text. I used the toggle function for that but it doesn't work and I don't know why. Can someone help me?
Here is the script:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
(".button").click(function() {

    $(".einleitung").toggle(1000);

});
});
```

And here is the text that I want hide:

```
<button class="button">Lesen</button>
    <div class="einleitung">
    <article class="article">
     <p><strong><em>My text.</em></strong></p>
    </article>
  </div>
```

Here is the link for Jquery:

```
<header>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</header>
```

Thanks for helping me:)

Comment: you are missing a `$` in `(".button").click(function() {`

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. Next time I control better my code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It working fine, You have missed `$` before `(".button")`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(".einleitung").toggle(1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">Lesen</button>
<div class="einleitung">
  <article class="article">
    <p><strong><em>My text.</em></strong></p>
  </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed $ in (".button").
Correct way $(".button")

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(".button").click(function(){  });`.`$` is used in jquery to `select a tag  and to apply action on it.`

Answer (score 0):

$ is missing in code

Correct code :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".button").click(function() {

    $(".einleitung").toggle(1000);

});
});
```

Hope this will help you!